# mobile.twitter redirect to login page

Tags: mobile, twitter, uiwebview

I have a strange problem.

When I try to open http://mobile.twitter.com/#!/istwebtv/tweets on uiwebview it is redirect to signup page ( https://mobile.twitter.com/signup)

If i try to open in MacOs safari browser the result is the same but it work in IOS safari browser.

Note : This link worked the last two weeks.
Where the problem can be ?

Thanks